# How can I create an input string that varies with how many iterations I have in R?

Tags: r

I would like to create a string that is dependent on an input number, chosen here to be 3:

```
c("Num 1", "Num 2", "Num 3")
```

Is there a way I can create a loop or something else where the output is exactly what is returned above?

Comment: `f <- function(x) paste("Num", seq(x)); f(3)`

Comment: or `sapply(1:3, FUN = function(x) paste('Num',x))`